# unable to publish values of costmap_2d occupancy grid

Tags: ros

Here's how my code looks -

```
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS *global_costmap = new costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS("global_costmap", buffer);
```

I have specified the following params in my configuration file -

```
global_frame: odom
rolling_window: true
track_unknown_space: true

plugins:
  - {name: obstacles_laser,           type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
  - {name: inflation,                 type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

I am able to publish the occupancy grid using the terminal by running rostopic echo -n1 /global_costmap/costmap.

However, when I add the following line to my code -

```
unsigned char* global_og = global_costmap->getCostmap()->getCharMap() ; 

cout << global_og[10] << endl;
```

I see some strange characters being published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue by using `cout << (int)global_og[10] << endl;`

I needed to cast the `unsigned char` to `int`.